# clearing JTexxtField when input restricted to Integers

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I have a JTextFieldand I am trying to clear the text  of the field by using textfield.setText(null);.But I an using document filter to restrict input to integers.Due to this it shows run time error.What shoul i do?

here is my code snippet

```
    PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) sid.getDocument();    
    doc.setDocumentFilter(new NumDocumentFilter());

    class NumDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {    

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
               AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

            Document doc = fb.getDocument();    
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
            sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));    
            sb.insert(offset, string);    
            if (test(sb.toString())) {    
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            } else {

            }
    }

    private boolean test(String text) {

      try {    
         Integer.parseInt(text);    
         return true;    
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {    
         return false;
      }
   }

    @Override
      public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
         AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }

   }

   @Override
   public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
         throws BadLocationException {
      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.delete(offset, offset + length);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.remove(fb, offset, length);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }``

   }
```

Comment: You should provide the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.replace(AbstractStringBuilder.java:797)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.replace(StringBuilder.java:266)
 at request.NumDocumentFilter.replace(NumDocumentFilter.java:50)

Comment: Why not just use a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html)

Comment: how can i post the whole stack trace here?

Comment: Press edit under the tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

used keylistener instead of document filter and its working fine.

textfieldObject.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
        getToolkit().beep();
        e.consume();
      }
    }
  });

Comment: -1 as the general rule, a keylistener is the _wrong_ approach. This rule is particularly true for input validation (misses copy/paste, f.i.) Instead, simply guard your filter against empty input (aka: null and "")